# what technologies inside liferay portal

Tags: java, liferay

I just curious about liferay portal, a famous Java portal. But I don't know, how many technologies integrated inside liferay an what are they?

Comment: Literally thousands ... which is too many to describe in an answer :-).  Seriously, if you really want to know, read the documentation and the source code.

Comment: Versions.html shows all the technologies used by Liferay Portal. Path to versions.html: <path-to-liferay-portal>/license/versions.html. For example: D:\liferay\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\license\versions.html.

Answer (score 7):

Liferay is built using the most popular Enterprise Java development stack these days, which is Spring on Hibernate. The web side of it uses JSPs and the Struts framework, which is from the days when Struts was the de facto Java web framework. The client side UI uses a JavaScript framework called AlloyUI, which is developed internally at Liferay and is built on the Yahoo YUI user interface library.

There are also several other frameworks that make the nuts and bolts of the portal, including an in-house BPM engine called Kaleo, Apache JackRabbit and Lucene for content management and indexing among others.

If you want to learn more about Liferay and would like to start developing for it, their Developer and Advanced developer courses are excellent and well get you productive very quickly, given you have already mastered Java and know a little JavaScript and CSS. Check [this](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Logical+Architecture) page if you haven't already for an overview of the logical architecture of the portal and the mix of open source components that make it tick. Also check the [tech specs](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/tech-specs) page, which provides a list of all technologies and frameworks that are employed.